# How to set gmail icon for non-gmail email?

Tags: gmail, gmail-imap

I would like to get an answer how to make an email which is not made in gmail but can be accessed through it to have an icon. I mean something like info@mysite.com to have gmail icon. I have also heard that you have to pay money somewhere for this. Is there a way to get it for free?

Comment: You question is not very clear. Please improve your question

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/th0mhfhwkrhwnep/stackui.png I want to have icon like info@android24.lt has. Also in my case it wouldn't be @gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

check out https://www.google.com/work/apps/business/products/gmail/

Basically if you have a website mysite.com then you can configure all incoming email for info@mysite.com to be redirected to gmail servers.

For this you will have to pay gmail. You can login using info@mysite.com and password at gmail.com page to send and receive e-mails from info@mysite.com.

Comment: Is there a way to get it for free?

Comment: I think google provides a free 30 day trial. http://setup.googleapps.com/Home/enterprise-business . But you will have to pay if you want to use it after trial runs out.